# Remote Image and stylesheet do not load in locally generated HTML but load correctly when opened in browser

Tags: apache

Running an Apache web server on an AWS server.  This occurred after a restart and some updates (I don't think Apache was updated).  Server version: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)
I create an HTML file to embed in emails.  It uses images and stylesheet from the remote web server.    Viewing the file locally or in an email the stylesheet and one of the images do not load (Firefox error NS_ERROR_GENERATE_FAILURE)  Other images load.  The stylesheet and image that do not load are in different directories from each other and the images that load properly.
If I enter the stylesheet path into my browser it displays as does the image.

I don't see any errors in the Apache logs.
sudo apachectl configtest shows no errors
Tried different browsers and clearing cache and different computers

Comment: Error in DevTools are?  Can you share them?

Comment: Only errors I see are in the Network tab, the NS_ERROR_GENERATE_FAILURE.  I'm not seeing how to more in the devtools.  There is no response.